# Integrating JaxRS REST service with WebSockets

Tags: java, rest, websocket, jax-rs, publish-subscribe

I'm attempting to develop a social network that implements publisher-subscribe pattern (kind of like Twitter does): users can follow people, therefore being notified when a new publication of their followers is sent.

All I have now is a working REST service implemented with JaxRS, running over Tomcat 7, offering services for login, register, getting profiles data and submitting posts. Servlet Mapping is done via web.xml

[My JaxRS app config](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/java/myusick/api/ApplicationConfig.java)

[RestServices](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/java/myusick/api/RestServices.java)

[Web.xml](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)

But the weight of the application comes from the pubsub part. And here is where things become messy.

Before speaking of technologies and implementation, the life cycle of this pubsub:

Let be A and B some users of the app and A follows (is subscribed to) B.

1. A navigates to his "timeline", therefore registering a WebSocket endpoint in the server from which he will receive notifications when any of the people he's suscribed to publishes anything. (A, himself, would be the topic?)
2. B publishes a new post, it's sent to JaxRS service via HTTP POST /post.
3. Server stores publication in database and then sends it to listening subscribers via WebSocket. As A is alive and listening, the publication is sent through his WebSocket/topic.
4. A gets notified of the new publication.

I've worked with Java built-in WebSockets (javax.websocket), Spring websockets (via STOMP) and JavaScript either built-in and SockJS. I know JaxRS has something called Server Sent Events that act like websockets but I'm absolutely lost on how to initialize and work with them.

My doubts:

1) Could I "mix" e.g Spring Websockets with my JaxRS server and how would it be initialized?

2) With JaxRS and SSE, can I dynamically create WS endpoints on the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really the full answer, but you may want top check Atmosphere, which supports 1) and 2) https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere. Just take a look at http://goo.gl/s7OwGc

Comment: oh nice, gonna try it, will post a response if I get to solve it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally made a workaround using Jersey's Server Sent Events, though not supported by IE, but works for what I needed

Here is the code for the [SSEProvider](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/java/myusick/controller/SSEProvider.java) and [SSEDispatcher](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/java/myusick/controller/SSEDispatcher.java)

[Gradle dependency](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/build.gradle#L16)

And front end [connection](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/services.js#L3) and [handlers](https://github.com/RecuencoJones/ArquiSoft/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/controllers/mainController.js#L45-62)

Also some docs on [HTML5 SSE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

Comment: Worth mentioning that IE is supported with the use of a polyfill, e.g. [here](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) or [here](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js)