# Is it possible to use jersey and java websockets (ServerEndpoint) in the same project

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, websocket, jersey

While I was developing a rest api application with jersey, I came to a point that I needed to implement a websocket endpoint for a particular piece of business logic.

I am using maven in my project so I added javax:javaee-api dependency, but when I entered the server endpoint annotation (@ServerEndpoint) it couldn't be resolved. I tried to import it manualy (import javax.websocket.*) and I saw that in the javax package there was no websocket sub-package, only ws,xml,swing,validation,etc. I tried to add javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api as a dependency instead of whole javaee-api, but I got the same result.

I searched on the web and on stackoverflow I found this question ([Integrating JaxRS REST service with WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785258/integrating-jaxrs-rest-service-with-websockets)) that is similar to mine but still has no answer about websockets. The guy that asked this question, solved his problem using jersey's SSE (Server-Sent Events).

My question is (as the title says): Is it possible to use jersey and java websockets in the same project, or i need to create a separate project and use reference or some kind of custom made broker class.

On request of Paul Wasilewski I append my pom.xml below. As you can see I added javaee-api dependency in the pom, but is not downloaded in the external libs (I use IntelliJ). I created new (clean) maven project and added the same dependency. In this new project, the javaee-api artifact was downloaded perfectly and I can access javax.websocket namespace.

I ask this question because I think that there is some dependency conflict in jersey with the javaee-api artifact.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.finki.misw.busline</groupId>
<artifactId>busline</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>busline</name>

<build>
    <finalName>busline</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Sure you can use websocket and jersey in the same project. To help you more please show us your pom.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can use `websocket` and `rs` services in the same project.

To add `websocket` support to your maven project add the following dependency to your `pom`.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I know that the server has this lib and therefore I can add provided scope, but my @ServerEndpoint cannot be resolved because maven cannot download the package and put it into IntelliJ's external lib directory. btw tnx for the answer.

Comment: @anchor, Why can't maven download this lib?

Comment: dunno. I tried mvn dependency:resolve, also mvn dependency get... Nothing worked..

Comment: I found my problem. I have added the javaee-api dependency in the dependencyManagement tag instead of the dependencies tag. anyway thanks for your support @Paul Wasilewski.